# Completion of Metric Spaces: Is an isometric embedding map necessary?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, definition, complete-spaces

> Call a metric space $Y$ a *completion* of a metric space $X$ if $X$ is dense in $Y$ and $Y$ is complete. State and prove a uniqueness theorem for completions of metric spaces.

I've read now in several places that completions of metric spaces are unique up to isometry, and also found a detailed proof [here](http://www.iiserpune.ac.in/%7Esupriya/teaching/Topology-MTH322/files/Completion.pdf). However, the framework followed in the attached link is not the same as what Rudin calls a *completion*. The PDF attached says that: A completion of a metric space $(X,d)$ is a pair consisting of a complete metric space $(Y,d')$ and an isometry $\phi: X\to Y$ such that $\phi(X)$ is dense in $Y$. On the other hand, Rudin does not bring in a map $\phi$, and directly says (as above in quoted text) that $Y$ is a completion of $X$ if $\overline{X} = Y$ and $Y$ is complete.

Is it possible to avoid the map $\phi: X\to Y$ as given [here](http://www.iiserpune.ac.in/%7Esupriya/teaching/Topology-MTH322/files/Completion.pdf), or is it necessary? I'm unable to come up with a uniqueness theorem given **Rudin's definition** of **completion of metric spaces**. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: It's necessary.  The isometric embedding function can be viewed as the identity function,  with the proper viewpoint of modding by cauchy sequences, so is often ignored by abuse of notation later on

Comment: I see. So in that case, Rudin should have been clearer about what is referred to by a *completion*, right? Without $\phi$ I don't seem to be getting anywhere.

Comment: Rudin is pretty well known for being terse, yes.  We identify the image of $\phi$ with the original set through abuse of language/notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We always need such a map $\phi$, but if $X$ is actually a subset of $Y$, then $\phi$ can be taken to be the inclusion map $\iota: X \hookrightarrow Y$.

Another typical choice: $Y$ is taken to be the set of all Cauchy sequences of elements in $X$ (modulo the obvious equivalence relation), and $X$ is identified with the subset of constant sequences (so the map $\phi(x) := (x, x, x, ...)$)